How to solve the diferential equation $(1+t^2)y' + ty^3=0$
How can i solve this differential equation? I tried using $z=y^3$ and $z'=2y^2  y'$ and got
$$(1+t^2) \frac{z'}{2y^2} + tz=0$$
but the I don't know how to do
Any suggestions?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is a separable ode.

You may also notice this is a Bernoulli equation after rewriting$$(1+t^2)y^{-3}y'+t=0$$and substituting $z=y^{-2}$, though the resulting ODE is also separable.

I edited my answer. I actually thought t was constant :")

It's a separable ode, as stated by @Chinny84 .
HINT
$$ y^{-3} dy = \frac{-t}{1+t^2} dt $$
Now integrate on both sides. Assume $u=1+t^2 \implies du=2t \ dt $
$$\int y^{-3} \ dy = \int \frac{-du}{2u} \ du \implies \frac{y^{-2}}{-2}=\frac{-\ln|1+t^2|}{2}+C_1$$
$$\implies y^{-2} = \ln |1+t^2| -2C_1$$
Thus $$y=±\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln|1+t^2|+C}},C=-2C_1$$

I suspect that in this exercise, $y$ is a function of $t$, instead of a function of $x$.

@JohnWaylandBales is it alright now?
